# How much bandwidth do I generate to destination web site with my curl code?

Tags: php, bandwidth, web-analytics

I use this function to load some source from another web site.

```
function getWebPageSourceCurl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0');
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}
```

How much bandwidth do I generate to destination web site? When I call this function does server also load images or just source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will only load the `$url` (presumably just the static/dynamic outputted HTML) specified, the amount of bandwidth will depend entirely on how big the page is. It's impossible to say.

Comment: Tnx for fast replay.

for example if this is page (and image is 2MB)
<pre>
<img src="image.jpg" />
</pre>

and when i load this page is generated bandwith only length of html source (couple of bytes in this example) or html + img size

Comment: Just the few bytes of the HTML. It won't automatically open a new connection and download images etc

Comment: Tnx Dotmister, i just make test to be sure and apache acces log show that only html file is loaded.